# Rails 2 to Rails 3 : using link_to instead of link_to_remote (including remote and update)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax, ruby-on-rails-3, link-to

A quick and easy answer I'm sure. 
I'm upgrading a Rails project from version 2 to version 3 and replacing a load of the link_to_remote with link_to's as per the Rails 3 update. Even something as simple as :

```
<%= link_to "Check Time",
        {:action=>:get_time}, :remote=>true, :update=>'current_time' %>
<div id='current_time'></div>
```

doesn't seem to work. The request (using get method) is going through ok and the rendered html is :

```
<a href="/monitoring/get_time" data-remote="true" update="current_time">Check Time</a>
```

Routes.rb entry :

```
get "monitoring/get_time"
```

As I say I'm sure this is a very obvious issue on my part!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The `:update` option isn't supported by the new `link_to :remote => true`.

You will either have to

- use the [legacy plugin](https://github.com/rails/prototype_legacy_helper)
- write the JS/AJAX yourself instead of using `:remote => true`
- use `render :update { |page| p.replace_html ... }`

Comment: You don't need to completely replace :remote => true. Use it, and bind the built in callback events from rails.js: 'ajax:before', 'ajax:complete', 'ajax:success', 'ajax:failure'.

Comment: The article ["Unobtrusive JavaScript in Rails 3"](http://bit.ly/aCdHWY) is a bit dated (June 8th, 2010) but has some examples of binding on these events.

Answer (score 7):

The `:update` parameter is gone. You need to handle the DOM update yourself using Unobtrusive JavaScript. Also, make sure you actually included the `csrf_meta_tag` helper in your layout.

I wrote an article about [using unobtrusive JavaScript in Rails 3](http://www.simonecarletti.com/blog/2010/06/unobtrusive-javascript-in-rails-3/).

Comment: csrf_meta_tag included in main layout. Seems to be the one problem with Ruby, functionality appearing and disappearing almost overnight.
I can understand the reason to remove :update but it was a very useful bit of code!
Thanks for your help.

Comment: Yep I meant Rails :-) 
Can't you tell I'm a PHP coder having to get to grips with Ruby :-)
Great article by the way!