# Simple AJAX example

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax

I have a controller:

```
class QuestionsController < ApplicationController
  def hello
    puts "====================!!!==================="
    @hello = "hey"
    "some"
  end

  def test
  end
```

test.rhtml:

```
<%= javascript_include_tag :defaults %>

<br/>
Click this link to show the current 
<br/>

<%= link_to "hello", 
    { :controller => "questions", :action => "hello" },
    :update => 'time_div', 
    :remote => true %>.

<br/>
<div id='time_div'>
  ...
</div>
```

When I click on 'hello' link I see that hello() method was called, but html page remains the same.  Why?

How do I need to change code to update HTML page?

Here is generated HTML page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Stack</title>


  <script src="/javascripts/jquery.js?1286229922" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/javascripts/jquery-ujs.js?1286229922" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <meta name="csrf-param" content="authenticity_token"/>
<meta name="csrf-token" content="UKPX1dNCZhyTk8u71hR9KaUmufIire7Rhvg8t7cRSlM="/>

</head>

<body>



<br/>
Click this link to show the current 
<br/>

<a href="/questions/hello" data-remote="true">hello</a>
<br/>

<div id='time_div'>
  ...
</div>



</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Which version of rails you are using???

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5511787/rails-2-to-rails-3-using-link-to-instead-of-link-to-remote-including-remote-an

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can have your hello action like this:

```
def hello
  #### your code goes here #####
  respond_to do |format|
    format.js { render :layout=>false }
  end
end
```

And one file hello.js.erb

```
$("#time_div").html("some text");
```

And your link will be:

```
<%= link_to "hello", { :controller => "questions", :action => "hello" }, :remote => true %>.
```

Comment: 1. Where do I need to put hello.js.erb? view\questions\hello.js.erb ? 2. Do I need to install jQuery?

Comment: Yes... you need jquery. And you need to keep hello.js.erb in /views/questions folder

Comment: I cannot make it work. I will be thankfull if you look at my code (https://github.com/demas/test_ruby_ajax) and give me information about my mistake.

Comment: I think you need rails.js for jquery. You still have rails.js for prototype. Just update it and include it in your layout file.

Comment: It doesn't help https://github.com/demas/test_ruby_ajax/commit/95f2a19e2b1918a1db084e84ce57ff7345b1cce8

Comment: You are still using prototype version of rails.js...Update this file for JQuery version. And you dont need to include application.js file

Comment: Like this https://github.com/demas/test_ruby_ajax/commit/41f4e24ecbacb802fc1bb18e2746ae34e0cdd270#diff-0

Comment: Use $("#time_div").html("some text"); in your hello.js.erb file and check

Comment: Added rails.js but still same issue :) added to manifest and restarted

Answer (score 3):

problem here is you are not returning anything from the controller action, Since you are using AJAX you need to return the result as either .js or jason

have a look at this example, with rails3 and Jquery

https://github.com/nu7hatch/rails3-ujs-example

cheers

sameera

Comment: thanks for this example link :-) very helpful to clear the concept of ajax in rails :-) +1 !