# Rails 3: Simple problem rendering :text via link_to (beating my head against the wall)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I am switching from 2.3.x to 3.0.7 and I am stuck doing the simplest of things.

I am just trying to create a link to remote, but it doesn't seem to work correctly.

From index.html.erb

```
<%= link_to "test", test_path, :remote => true, :update => "test_div" %>
<div id="test_div"></div>
```

From home_controller.rb

```
def index  
end

def test
    render :text => 'test'
end
```

From routes.rb

```
match '/' => 'home#index'
match '/test', :to => 'home#test'
```

Should be simple stuff.  I click the link the "test" and in server console:

```
Rendered home/index.html.erb within layouts/application (15.6ms)
Completed 200 OK in 31ms (Views: 31.2ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)

Started GET "/test" for 127.0.0.1 at Fri May 06 20:15:03 -0400 2011
  Processing by HomeController#test as JS
Rendered text template (0.0ms)
Completed 200 OK in 16ms (Views: 15.6ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
```

In firebug it says:

```
GET http://localhost:3001/test 304 Not Modified 40ms    

Response

test
```

Nothing shows up in my test_div.  I don't understand, what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`:update` has been removed from Rails 3.  You can see [Rails 2 to Rails 3 : using link_to instead of link_to_remote (including remote and update)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5511787/rails-2-to-rails-3-using-link-to-instead-of-link-to-remote-including-remote-an) for some details and some pointers on other ways of getting what you need.

Comment: Oh snap, you have to write js yourself now.  Cool, it makes sense. Thanks.