# Render Link_to_remote via ajax in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am working in rails 2. I want to make an link_to_remote object and render it on html page. I want to send date via ajax. I am trying this.

```
render :text => "<font color='"+ color +"'>" +params[:ajax_status] + "</font>" + <%= link_to_remote '| Undo',
              :update => 'status_'" +params[:ajax_status]+ ",:url => {:controller => 'requests', :action => 'action_on_punching_request', :id => "+ params[:id] +" :ajax_status => 'Undo'} %>
```

But unable to proceed. It shows on webpage

```
Accepted<%= link_to_remote '| Undo', :update => 'status_'Accepted,:url => {:controller => 'requests', :action => 'action_on_punching_request', :id => 20 :ajax_status => 'Undo'} %>
```

PLease help me out.

Comment: i think u r concatinating the link code to a string and hence its getting displayed on view.

Comment: u may also have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5511787/rails-2-to-rails-3-using-link-to-instead-of-link-to-remote-including-remote-a

Comment: Check out the API documentation for [link_to_remote](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/PrototypeHelper/link_to_remote).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need the `<%= %>` tags, in this case - they're for erb.

Try just:

```
render :text => "#{ content_tag :font, params[:ajax_status], :color => color }#{  link_to_remote '| Undo', :update => "status_#{ params[:ajax_status] }", :url => {:controller => 'requests', :action => 'action_on_punching_request', :id => params[:id], :ajax_status => 'Undo'}  }"
```

Comment: Also, this is stating to get a little too view-y for a controller... You might consider moving this in a view file (js.rjs, or something).

Comment: Yup, i included js file to excute this task.