# Rails 4 - Ajax. Timer implementation

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ajax, ruby-on-rails-4

I have sample application, which works fine, but needs older Rails' version. 
Here is controller code:

```
class AjaxController < ApplicationController
  def show
  end

  def time
    render text: "The current time is #{Time.now.to_s}"
  end
end
```

And here is view code:

```
<%= javascript_include_tag :defaults %>
<h1>Ajax show</h1>
Click this link to show the current 
<%= link_to_remote "time", 
    :update => 'time_div', 
    :url => {:action => "time"} %>.<br/>
<div id='time_div'>
</div>
```

Rails 4.0.2 doesn't have 'link_to_remote', but does have :remote attribute in 'link_to'. But this code doesn't work even with this replacement. What should I do? Thank you.

Comment: Please post your updated view code with `link_to` which isn't working.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Rails 2 to Rails 3 : using link\_to instead of link\_to\_remote (including remote and update)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5511787/rails-2-to-rails-3-using-link-to-instead-of-link-to-remote-including-remote-a)